# Permanently change maximum CPU frequency

Tags: cpu, frequency

So far I've found temporary solution for my problem at [Maximum CPU frequency stuck at low value](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303882/maximum-cpu-frequency-stuck-at-low-value), but the question that I have is how to make it permanent. Right after reboot, frequencies are set back to stock 1.90GHz.

```
CPU Model = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies = 2401000 2400000 2300000 2200000 2100000 1900000 1800000 1700000 1600000 1500000 1400000 1300000 1100000 1000000 900000 800000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/boost = 1
```

Some other information that might be, or not, relevant:

```
vitaliy:~$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/bios_limit 1900000
```

and...

```
vitaliy:~$ cat /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc0
```

From what I've noticed, `ignore_ppc` and `scaling_available_frequencies` are overwritten every time on boot/reboot. Not sure for `bios_limit`.

Comment: Does this help ?  http://askubuntu.com/a/179920/71679

Comment: No such file as _cpufreqd.conf_ in Ubuntu 13.04...

Comment: @VitaliyP. please, instead of editing your question add an answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, the problem was at *bios_limit*.

To start, override any BIOS limitations by setting **ignore_ppc** to **1**:

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/processor/parameters/ignore_ppc
```

Then, change CPU **scaling_max_freq** for all cores using this *script* [pay attention to core's numbers! In my case quad-core, core's numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3]:

```
for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-3]/cpufreq/;do 
  echo 2400000 > $x/scaling_max_freq
done
```

Source: http://blog.patshead.com/2013/04/my-bios-is-limiting-my-cpu-clock-speed.html

Now, since you can't edit **bios_limit** files, you have to force kernel to ignore it.

Edit **/etc/default/grub** (you need to do this using root privilege) and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash processor.ignore_ppc=1"
```

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and reboot.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/856233 Comment Nº 24.

Now the CPU frequencies are at 2.4GHz, as desired, while using AC power.

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2400000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = ondemand
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =   800000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  2400000 [kHz]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a script which performs the temporary solution, then make the script run on every boot, by adding the script in System > Preferences > Startup Applications or in [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

Comment: At the beginning was trying your suggestion, the one that led me to the correct answer. Thank you