# How do I set the max processor state in Ubuntu?

Tags: cpu

How do I set the max processor state in Ubuntu? Windows provides an interface where max and min processor states and active and passive fan policy settings can be set. Is there an analogous interface available in Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change min and max cpu frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057710/change-min-and-max-cpu-frequency)

Comment: Also, some of your power settings are controlled through BIOS. It would help to know the make and model of your computer as some laptops (like Dell) have different power saving features.'

Comment: The interface pictured above is available across multiple bios environments on different computers.

Comment: Note that this not frequency or clocking. It is the percentage of processor utilization.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is probably using [TLP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/utils/tlp), you can see e.g. the scaling options here: https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#scaling. Of course all the settings here modify something in `/sys` but it's probably safer doing it through TLP.

Unfortunately TLP doesn't do fan control, but you may want to look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/520547/how-to-change-the-system-cooling-policy-on-linux-mint-debian-laptop) for alternative methods.