# CPU runs at the minimum speed after disconnecting the socket and rebooting

Tags: boot, 16.04, performance

If I shutdown my PC, then remove the connection to the socket and boot it again, the CPU runs at a minimum possible 480MHz. But if I then reboot it again, this time, without removing the socket, the frequency is normal. If you haven't understood yet:

1. Shut my PC.
2. Remove the socket connection.
3. Reboot after a while.

Result: Frequency of 480MHz(which is the minimum possible) and very slow running and booting.

1. Shut down the PC.
2. Don't remove the socket.
3. Reboot

Result: The frequency is back to normal.

Note that I have a laptop with a battery that doesn't work which needs to be constantly plugged in so that I can do my work.

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit.
CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N3050 @ 1.6GHz
Product : Inspiron 14-3452 (06AC)
Max frequency: 2160MHz
Min frequency: 480MHz
```

Additional info:

Normal boot:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:22
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:22
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:33
```

Slow boot(480MHz):

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor:powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:22
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:22
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:33
```

Comment: When you say you "disconnet the socket" do you mean you the battery AC charger plug? Also not a fix but you can probably use this script to reset min/max CPU freq on the fly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057710/change-min-and-max-cpu-frequency

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You are right, I meant the charger plug. I knew I could just change the CPU frequency but the problem I am experiencing is not normal, something bigger must be wrong, so I am trying to better not mess up anything(so no one in the real world blames me, now that they will blame you, I may try it, if I have no choice, but it's kinda okayyy for now).

Comment: The frequency controlled by Intel pstate can be hardware or software controlled. Also it can be overridden at boot time via grub or can be set in BIOS. There is an expert here in **Ask Ubuntu** on the subject and I will email him a link to your question.

Comment: Laptop brand and model number please. If the battery is broken, then likely BIOS is getting confused. Your workaround seems fine. Just don't unplug it if you don't have to. show us `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*` under both conditions.

Comment: @DougSmythies Do I need to show these after the boot in which it runs at 480MHz, normal one, anyone, both or during the boot?

Comment: Both, after boot. One set when it runs at 480MHz and one set when it runs normally.

Comment: @DougSmythies I've added all the requested info unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: no reason revealed. better look at `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_m*`, which I should have thought of to begin with (but those numbers are not supposed to disagree with the pct numbers). If still nothing, then likley BIOS is doing it. Laptop brand and model please. If Dell, yes messes from BIOS all the time.

Comment: @DougSmythies Yes it's Dell. What exactly do you mean by model? I think I have misunderstood. The directory you gave now, seems to show the max and min frequencies which I have already given, do I need to show it again, I will, if you say so, I have checked it in both conditions through `cpufreq-info` already and it is the same for both CPUs and in both conditions.

Comment: @DougSmythies This is probably due to the computer realizing that there is no power and lower the frequency to sustain the low power or just a bug. Devices these days probably aren't designed to handle no battery situations. It must be due to that. This mystery is mostly solved. Thank You for all the help, this problem has probably been solved for how much it can be and I am satisfied with this much. I don't really need fixing the problem because it's more like fixing my battery is needed.

Comment: Agreed. Dell forces CPU frequency overrides depending on battery or AC or not using their power adpater or ...