# Change Frequency But nothing different

Tags: performance, frequency

My problem here:

```
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# sh MinPower.sh 
CPU MHz:               1200.000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# lscpu | grep MHz
CPU MHz:               1200.000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# python TestCpu.py 
11.3900308609
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# sh MaxPower.sh 
CPU MHz:               2700.000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# lscpu | grep MHz
CPU MHz:               2700.000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# python TestCpu.py 
11.4552109241
```

Here is MaxPower.sh

```
modprobe cpufreq_userspace
cpufreq-set -c 0 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 1 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 2 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 3 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 4 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 5 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 6 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 7 -u 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 0 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 1 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 2 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 3 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 4 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 5 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 6 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 7 -d 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 0 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 1 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 2 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 3 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 4 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 5 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 6 -f 2.7GHz
cpufreq-set -c 7 -f 2.7GHz
lscpu | grep MHz
```

Here is TestCpu.py

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
i=0
while (i<50000000):
    i+=1
print time.time() - start_time
```

The question is why there is nothing different between 2 frequency ?

Comment: do you have intel?

Comment: yes. i already config /etc/default/grub so it will run cpufreq-set perfecty

Comment: is there any output when you run the command `dpkg -l | grep cpufrequtils`?

Comment: root@LeAn:~# dpkg -l | grep cpufrequtils
ii  cpufrequtils                          008-1                              amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass cpufrequtils if it's not installed or not working these commands will adjust your frequency:

to set the high and low frequency boundaries is to use the following commands:

First, list supported frequencies:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

To list the current low boundary set use this command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

or list the max:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

To set the low to 1200 for example, use this command:

```
echo "1200000" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

To set the max to 2700 for example use this command:

```
echo "2700000" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
```

The default `governor` is set to "ondemand" and will only max out if needed or under system load. The CPU will not clock high under low load. To set the CPU to a static frequency, use "performance" and set the max_freq to the desired frequency.

To list available governors, use the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors
```

To list current governor, use the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

To set the current governor to performance, use this command:

```
echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```

You can even adjust the individual cores by substituting cpu* with the actual cpu such as cpu0, cpu1, cpu2, or cpu3 depending on how many cores you have.

[here is some more info](http://blog.tube42.se/?p=1225)

Comment: I'm using kali linux and can't get indicator-cpufreq
But i think if lscpu tell MHz is right so using indicator-cpufreq or command line cpufreq-set is the same ...

Comment: no it's not the same. I've updated the answer.

Comment: `root@LeAn:~/Desktop# sh MaxPower.sh 
CPU MHz:               2700.000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
2700000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
2700000
root@LeAn:~/Desktop# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor
userspace`

Comment: @LêÂn set it to performance and it should override whatever is holding you back see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/179543/the-performance-governor-for-cpufreq-doesnt-seem-to-behave-as-advertised

Comment: First, set it to  performance like so: `echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` then run TestCpu.py. Next, set the min freq to 1200 like so `echo "1200000" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` and the max also to 1200 `echo "1200000" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` TestCpu.py  should now show a different value.

Comment: root@LeAn:~/Desktop# python TestCpu.py 
11.2585771084
Still the same result ...
I think it's the hardware problem. This laptop is ENVY dv7. Original system is core i5 but after send back to HP (Hewlett Packard) for fixing something they replace core i5 by core i7 and in the BIOS i can't access anything to the CPU. Even in win 8 it still have only one frequency 1.16 GHz. Maybe they (HP company) block it frequency.

Comment: @LêÂn yeah, BIOS usually has the final say. One last note, I applied these commands on my system and I do not have cpufreq-utils installed so maybe that makes a difference IDK?

Comment: No itsn't. Just stay at the same :D

Answer (score 0):

The default governor is set to "ondemand" and will only max out if needed or under system load. The CPU will not clock high under low load. To set the CPU to a static frequency, use "performance" and set the max_freq to the desired frequency.